# Multiple Inputs with different sample size in Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I am working on a specific neural network which gets two different inputs:

- the MNIST data set, the train set is a [50000,784] tensor
- an auxiliary vector with the TensorShape([Dimension(28)])]

When I define and run the model it as to below

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras.objectives import binary_crossentropy
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
import numpy as np
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def load_dataset(flatten=False):
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    # normalize x
    X_train = X_train.astype(float) / 255.
    X_test = X_test.astype(float) / 255.
    # we reserve the last 10000 training examples for validation
    X_train, X_val = X_train[:-10000], X_train[-10000:]
    y_train, y_val = y_train[:-10000], y_train[-10000:]
    if flatten:
        X_train = X_train.reshape([X_train.shape[0], -1])
        X_val = X_val.reshape([X_val.shape[0], -1])
        X_test = X_test.reshape([X_test.shape[0], -1])
    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test
X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = load_dataset(True)

original_dim=784
m = 100 #batchsize
n_z =8
n_epoch = 10
n_d =int(n_z*(n_z - 1 )/2) #or n_d=28

A_vec = K.random_normal(shape=(n_d,), mean=0., stddev=1.)
image_inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
A_inputs = Input(shape=(n_d,))
inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([image_inputs, A_inputs])

h_q1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(inputs)
h_q2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(h_q1)
h_q3 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(h_q2)
h_q4= Dense(64, activation='relu')(h_q3)
mu = Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(h_q4)
log_sigma = Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(h_q4)

 ............
```

After running the model,

```
vae.fit([X_train,A_vec], outputs,shuffle=True, batch_size=m, epochs=n_epoch)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of
>   samples. Got array shapes: [(50000, 784),
>   TensorShape([Dimension(28)])]

It means my inputs have different sizes. How can I use differetn inputs when they have different sizes (or shapes)?

Comment: What is the purpose of this second vector? You need to have one different vector for each sample?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro My model is a density estimation and I want to find the distribution of a multivariate Gaussian distribution that explains my data. The log_sigma contains the variance values while I want to add a dependency between the model variables. This vector helps me to estimate the covariance and correlation between the variables. In fact, it is an auxiliary initialization of dependencies between my variables. So, I think I do not need different vectors for each sample, only one is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs have to have the same size, e.g. (50000, 748) and (50000, 28), i.e. one per sample. Try create a numpy array size (50000, 28) for `A_vec`: `numpy.random.normal(0., 1.0, (50000, 28)`.

Or if you want the same vector for all, create it and repeat 50000 times.